# Ubuntu 18.04: Hotspot with 2 wifi connections?

Tags: wireless, usb, connection, interface, adapter

Long story short, I have to stay at hotels for a few months so I'm trying to set up a hotspot on my laptop for my phone/other computers to pass through. On my laptop I have built-in wifi and a USB wifi stick, yet when I try to set up a hot spot, it won't let me connect to the internet with the usb wifi connection. Is there a way or a workaround so that i can have one connection as the access point and the other as the connection to the hotel wifi?

Answer (score 2):

You want to share internet access of WiFi A for Wifi B

1. Launch `nm-connection-editor` from terminal or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Select WiFi A, hit the cog.

   Go to IP Tab, then select 'Connection Sharing' in the drop down list.
3. Select WiFi B, hit the cog.

   Setup mode (hotspot or ah hoc).